# How do I send an email in Django with a certain mimetype?

Tags: python, django, smtp, email, mime

```
MYMESSAGE = "<div>Hello</div><p></p>Hello"
send_mail("testing",MYMESSAGE,"noreply@mydomain.com",['assdf@gmail.com'],fail_silently=False)
```

However, this message doesn't get the HTML mime type when it is sent. In my outlook, I see the code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#sending-alternative-content-types):

```
msg = EmailMessage(subject, html_content, from_email, [to])
msg.content_subtype = "html"  # Main content is now text/html
msg.send()
```

You can only change the subtype of the mimetype it seems. So it will always be

`"text/%s" % msg.content_subtype`